# Random Noise Effect On Signal Filtering in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I'm woking on signal processing and Filtering. i create a noisy signal and i want to use bandpass filter to get my desire frequency.
i generate noisy signal "y" by this code :

```
Fs = 16000;                    % Sampling frequency
fNy = Fs / 2;
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 60000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz , 5.8 , 12.6 , 120 Hz sinusoid
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t) +  sin(2*pi*5.8*t) +  sin(2*pi*12.6*t); 
x1 = 15.3 * sin(2*pi*15.5 * t );

a = 5.2;
b = 35.5;
r = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1); 
y = x + x1 + r*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise
```

and i filter my signal to get 15.5 Hz signal by FIR algorithm like Chebyshev. i use FDATool to design bandpass filter. like this :

```
Fs = 16000;  % Sampling Frequency

N             = 16 * 4096;     % Order
Fc1           = 15.48;    % First Cutoff Frequency
Fc2           = 15.52;    % Second Cutoff Frequency
flag          = 'scale';  % Sampling Flag
SidelobeAtten = 100;      % Window Parameter
% Create the window vector for the design algorithm.
win = chebwin(N+1, SidelobeAtten);

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIR1 function.
b  = fir1(N, [Fc1 Fc2]/(Fs/2), 'bandpass', win, flag);
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
```

and use filter function in matlab to get my desire signal :

```
filteredSignal = filter(Hd.Numerator,1,y);
max_amp = max(filteredSignal );
```

and after filtering i get maximum of signal amplitude. it is work fine. but there is a big problem for me. 
because of random noise i have diffrent values of filtered signal max.
 like :  `10.552 , 10.493 , 10.876 , 10.524 , 10.617`

and when i decrease value of random noise like this :

```
r = 0.001;
y = x + x1 + r*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise
```

i get this values of filterd signal maximum like :

```
10.541 , 10.541 ,10.541 , 10.541, 10.541
```

**and now my question is :
how to reduce or decrease noise effect on my filtered signal?   what should i do for get same value of max amplitude of signal after filtering?**

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fs = 16000;                    % Sampling frequency
fNy = Fs / 2;
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 200000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz , 5.8 , 12.6 , 120 Hz sinusoid
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t) +  sin(2*pi*5.8*t) +  sin(2*pi*12.6*t); 
x1 = 15.3 * sin(2*pi*15.5 * t );

a = 5.2;
b = 35.5;
r = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1); 
y = x + x1 + r*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise

N             = 16 * 4096;     % Order
Fc1           = 15.48;    % First Cutoff Frequency
Fc2           = 15.52;    % Second Cutoff Frequency
flag          = 'scale';  % Sampling Flag
SidelobeAtten = 100;      % Window Parameter
% Create the window vector for the design algorithm.
win = chebwin(N+1, SidelobeAtten);

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIR1 function.
b  = fir1(N, [Fc1 Fc2]/(Fs/2), 'bandpass', win, flag);
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);

filteredSignal = filter(Hd.Numerator,1,y);

Testim=1/15.5;
t0=0;
Ts=1/Fs;

steadyData=filteredSignal(100001:200000);

numAvr=100;

samLen=length(steadyData)/numAvr;

m=[];

for j=0:numAvr-1;

    s0=steadyData(1+j*samLen:j*samLen+samLen);

    Omega=fminbnd('jomega',(2*pi/Testim)*.9,(2*pi/Testim)*1.1, [0,1.0e-30 ], s0,t0,Ts);
    [Amplitude,Theta,RMS]=sinefit2(s0,Omega,t0,Ts);

    freq=Omega/(2*pi);

    if 15.4<=freq & freq<=15.6
        m=[m Amplitude];
    else
    end

end


avrAmp=(1/length(m))*sum(m)
```

I don't know what you want to do, exactly. But, in order to reduce noise effect hear, we could use least square method, if we know some information, such as frequency, sampling rate, etc. I give you an example.You can find the function 'sinefit2.m' at "http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3730-sinefit". I think, after fitting, the amplitude would be commonly more similar, but not always.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. i use this sample before. final result improve a little but it is not enough for me. at now I'm looking for some noise reduction or noise estimation algorithm. do have any information about it? thanks.

Comment: I changed the example a little. Noise reduction would be related to amount of information. I divided sample data in order to increase amplitude information, got estimated amplitudes, respectively, and averaged the amplitudes. If you want more accurate result, you would need to acquire data more, and increase number of average.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get always same amplitude, you should fix your random number. whenever you run your code, matlab will generate different random number, and SNR will be changed. The one way fixing random number is to initialize random number generator.

Please try following code.

```
Fs = 16000;                    % Sampling frequency
fNy = Fs / 2;
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 60000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector
% Sum of a 50 Hz , 5.8 , 12.6 , 120 Hz sinusoid
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t) +  sin(2*pi*5.8*t) +  sin(2*pi*12.6*t); 
x1 = 15.3 * sin(2*pi*15.5 * t );

a = 5.2;
b = 35.5;
rng(0,'twister') 
r = a + (b-a).*rand(1,1); 
rng(0,'twister')
y = x + x1 + r*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise

plot(y)
```

With these code you could see always the same signal y.

Comment: Thank you for replay, i want to simulate a real condition of a noisy system and and process some frequencies behavior. ( like phase,amplitude ,... )
in fact SNR of my signal change every time. i'm looking for a solution to reduce random noise effect on filtred signal. is there any idea to get SNR or any parameters of noisy signal that relate to filterd signal? in other hand how can i calculate a parameter from single noisy signal ( like snr or psnr ,... ) that relate to other Sinusoids signals?

thanks.

Comment: There is no 'magic' trick that would always transform a noisy signal exaclty back into the original. The algorithms are pretty efficient, but, as the amplitude of the noise increases with respect to the amplitude of the signal, you will have losses. Tell me if you want me to elaborate more in an answer

Comment: thank you very much. I'm looking for noise reduction algorithm to increase my calculation accuracy. would you please tell me what should i do for this? accuracy of amplitude of filtered signal is so important. i get this signal from vibration system. what is your idea?  thanks.

Comment: First, do you have some informations on the source of the noise (measurement equippment, vibrations inside the system)? Can you quantify this noise? Will you always use the same system/data acquiring process?

Comment: Vibration System involve a AC 3-phase motor and a circle plate that fixed on it's rotor. this system run at 15.5 Hz ( about 950 rpm ) and it is mechanical system, therefore there is some random noise that  generate by other part of mechanical system. motor speed control by an Inverter System , so there some noise by this inverter. other machines that are placed in near of vibration system , work in deference rpm like 120rpm , 560rmp and etc.  so my vibration sensor get all this frequencies and i have to filter sensor signal. i use  16 bit data acquisition card and my sample rate is 80 Kbps.

Comment: The idea that comes to my mind would be to run some tests with different operative conditions on your machine in order to design a specific noise filter for your system. Would take time though ^^

Comment: Do you have some real vibration data to share? Would be nice as a first step to run an fft on these datas and plot the Amplitude/Frequency graph in order to estimate the type of the random noise you get (if you're lucky and it looks like a white noise it'll be pretty easy). Do you want me to explain how to do it or can you do it by yourself and show us the results?